# Open popup on long press gesture like Whats app

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I want to open popup on long press gesture.
My application having UITableView and when user long press on UITableviewCell open popup. 
When user holding his finger long enough then only display popup. Not when user long press and releasing his finger.

I'm using below code:
Using this code when I releasing my finger the after pop will opened so that is wrong. I want to open popup on long press without releasing finger.

```
//Long press gesture
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture= [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = .4; //seconds
longPressGesture.delegate = self;
longPressGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
cell.titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[cell.titleLabel addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
```

Comment: Does this code work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 -(void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
  {
  //Start a timer and perform action after whatever time interval you want.
  }
  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
  {
  //Check the duration and if it is less than what you wanted, invalidate the timer.
  }
}
```

Comment: @Moni_BQ -  Awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take some action as soon as the long press begins then you have to check if state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and then write code which you want to execute when long press gesture begins. Try with below lines of code.

```
 -(void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
  {
  //Write code for open pop up.
  }
}
```